# How to make like premium upgrade of application using In app purchase v3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob, in-app-billing

I do а premium upgrade of applications (ad free version), and use for this In app purchase v3 http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html. Type of purchase is not controlled by Google. The main feature, I just did not consume the purchase, and a check make when you run the application, and advertising was removed. I`m testing this using the inAppid "android.test.purchased". But after some time (day, week, month) buying disappears and reappears advertising. Therefore, how to make a premium upgrade to be able to do the checking after purchase, without using your own server. SharedPreferences and SQLite are not suitable for this, because after you uninstall an application, data is lost, and purchase too. What type of purchase is better to choose, so that it is preserved for user forever. Need to make binding to Google Play account. Please advise how best to do so as it is very serious.

Comment: Unfortunately, your own server is the best way. Get a VPS from DigitalOcean or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use your own server. The simplest option might be to use something like Firebase instead of writing your own server code & DB.

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange that your purchase has disappeared after some time. Remember that test purchases will be cancelled by Google after 14 days.

If product was not consumed it will always restore and can't be purchased twice.

A good option is to have restore button somewhere in your app, forcing restore and providing feedback from any errors which may occur.

In my opinion you don't need a server or event local storage. Just check for purchase every launch